# What is ArcStorm from Esri?

Tags: arcgis-license-manager, arcinfo-workstation, arcstorm

I have licensed ArcStorm from Esri but have no idea what the product is.

I have found no documentation about it from Esri.

Answer (score 7):

As [commented by @Joseph](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/333523/what-is-arcstorm-from-esri/333539#comment544511_333523):

> ArcStorm (Arc Storage Manager) is ESRI’s implementation of
>   Client/Server technology for managing distributed ARC/INFO databases.
>   ArcStorm enables multiple users to edit the same layer concurrently
>   and uses a feature-level transaction locking mechanism to manage the
>   editing sessions.Traditional techniques of preventing simultaneous
>   editing of the same area, such as the one deployed by the Librarian
>   product from ESRI and Infomaster from SYNERCOM, allow graphic editing
>   by locking the entire tile or facet, even though only one or few
>   features are to be edited...

I worked with ArcStorm first as a prototype with Esri’s Prototype Lab (as their guest prior to a benchmark) in late 1992 and then in production for a number of years. It fell largely into disuse as the Spatial Database Engine (SDE) was adopted instead but, in its early days, it was highly innovative.

As [commented by @Spacedman](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/333523/what-is-arcstorm-from-esri/333539#comment544545_333523) Esri issued a Technical Paper on [Migrating Data From ArcStorm™ or Map Librarian to the Geodatabase](http://downloads.esri.com/support/whitepapers/ao_/MigrationfromArcStormJ9044.pdf) in June 2003.